# update startup page in Launch Screen.storyboard, startup App display white page,how to solve?

Tags: ios

My app startup page needs to be replaced,I update startup page in Launch Screen.storyboard,but i startup app,startup page changed white page.how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try by deleting existing app from device and installed again. If u are using simulator then Reset Content and settings.

Comment: @ Neha Gupta，thank you so much.I've tried this method.Is there any other way?

Comment: it was working before or this is the first time you implement it?

Comment: @ Mohammad Bashir Sidani , yes, before it can work normally, but after I have updated the start page images start pages blank.

Comment: @ Neha Gupta，Mohammad Bashir Sidani，Thanks，I have solve the problem, my approach is to restart the computer to release the cache and then shows the updated start page.